# soft body tree keeps falling apart

Tags: soft-body

I have a tree that I made with several objects and I joined them together but I put a soft body modifier on it and the leaves fall of the trunk how do I stop that from happening

Comment: you need to attach the .blend file or share some screenshots, because without them it's hard to understand your problem

Comment: You have to join the loose parts with faces. You can cut holes on the trunk with the knife tool and bridge them with "Bridge Edge Loops". But if you want to create animated trees I advise the Sampling Tree Gen. It's a built-in addon, just enable it in the preferences. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwDwPxNund0